# nix-shell did not create the server/client directories

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, nix-shell

I am trying to follow the instructions in https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/Ubuntu.html
The nix-shell command completes without any errors. But, I cannot **cd** to *plutus-plaground-server* or *plutus-playground-client* because these two directories were not created.
Below is the output of running nix-shell :

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus]$ nix-shell
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for Agda entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for cabal-install entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
nix-pre-commit-hooks: hooks up to date
pid 6368's current affinity list: 0-11
pid 6368's new affinity list: 0-11
```

These are the entries in **plutus** directory :
Any idea what I may be doing wrong ?

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus]$ ls
cabal.project       flake.lock  papers             plutus-metatheory           release.nix  result-5    stubs
ci.nix              flake.nix   plutus-benchmark   plutus-report               result       result-6    word-array
CONTRIBUTING.adoc   LICENSE     plutus-core        plutus-tx                   result-1     result-7
default.nix         nix         plutus-core-spec   plutus-tx-plugin            result-2     scripts
doc                 notes       plutus-errors      prettyprinter-configurable  result-3     shell.nix
extended-utxo-spec  NOTICE      plutus-ledger-api  README.adoc                 result-4     stack.yaml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like those folders are not in the git repo. I am running into same problem.

I am following instructions for MacOS from here:
https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html

And didn't realize it until i tried to build the playground client and server.

When i try to build with this command:
$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.client --option system x86_64-darwin

I get this error:
error: attribute 'plutus-playground' in selection path 'plutus-playground.client' not found

because the folder isn't there.

It looks like it has been removed. From this doc, I checked out the commit they mention:
https://tutorials.cardanoacademy.io/plutus-pioneer-program/setting-up-plutus-playground/cloning-plutus-repository

Like this:
$ git checkout 3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502

Now the folders are there.

Answer (score 5):

This is documentation drift. Those two applications have moved to the [plutus-apps repository](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps). If you do the same exact steps cloning plutus-apps instead of plutus repository, it will work.

Comment: Thank you! Builds now. plutus-pab not building with this command: $ nix-build -A plutus-pab

error is:
error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found

Comment: Please open another question for pan is you need assistance

Answer (score 0):

You have to create these directories yourself and the "nix.conf" file with the contents from https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus#iohk-binary-cache.

Maybe this video will help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cdu0gzCiYbY&t=758s

Comment: The nix.conf is fine. The video did not help.