# Error running plutus-playground-client in Linux

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-pab

I have successfully installed nix, cabal and have setup the IOHK binary cache. I cloned the plutus-app repository and successfully built the Haskell packages and other artifacts with nix. Then running nix-shell successfully I get into the nix-shell prompt:

```
[nix-shell:/home/datapool/plutus-apps]$
```

I then issue the following commands:

```
[nix-shell:/home/datapool/plutus-apps]$ cd plutus-playground-client
[nix-shell:/home/datapool/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$ npm run start
```

I then get this output:

```
> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start /home/datapool/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client
> plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev

 /nix/store/ry2hywgh6cmmm9d5b9566nxdskd752yc-plutus-playground-generate-purs/bin/plutus-playground-generate-purs: line 6: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! syscall spawn
 npm ERR! file sh
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `plutus-playground-generate-purs && 
 npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev`
 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/brightchip/.npm/_logs/2022-01-12T13_05_31_245Z-debug.log
```

As the output says, it seems to be looking for a non-existent /bin/plutus-playground-server.

Same problem when I run the server:

```
[nix-shell:/home/datapool/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$ plutus-playground-server
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
/nix/store/fm77y43lzpgnay4pyc48jwpln0lnmrk3-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I might be missing or how to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks related to an issue I ran into where the directories were missing.
I needed to git checkout a patch.

Possible solution - https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6251/6004

The instructions are at :

https://tutorials.cardanoacademy.io/plutus-pioneer-program/setting-up-plutus-playground/cloning-plutus-repository

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. The patch works:

```
git checkout 3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but doing this fixed it for me:

```
# In the plutus-apps folder
GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build ./default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-playground-server.components.exes.plutus-playground-server
# That will build a bash script somewhere (in store)
# edit that file located in this path:
whereis plutus-playground-server
# replace subshell (in Line 10) with the path from last nix-build command
# edit the file from this path: /nix/store/*-plutus-playground-generate-purs/bin/plutus-playground-generate-purs
# replace subshell (in Line 6) with the path from last nix-build command
cd plutus-playground-client
nix-shell
plutus-playground-server
```

Source: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/4246#issuecomment-738888246