# git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a for English Auction doesn't work

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

According to cabal.project script for the English Auction, the git branch for this plutus script is:

```
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
    tag: 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
```

But when I do a git checkout of the plutus-apps, I am unable to run the plutus-playground-server.

However when I use as different branch as discuss here:

[(Solved) Error running plutus-playground-client in Linux](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6296/solved-error-running-plutus-playground-client-in-linux)

I can run both server and client without a hitch but unfortunately the project script doesn't compile as it's in the wrong repository.

Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I used a more recent one `7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd` and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex
Yes that checkout allows me to build the server but I get this error when running the client:

```
/bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
```

So I am able to run the server but not the client on that commit.